# AJAX POST, form data in network monitor shows valid JSON being sent but I still get a syntax error?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I am trying to make an AJAX post that sends JSON to an express server. The browser's console error says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0". When I copy the JSON being sent from network, headers, form data into a validator it says that this is valid JSON.

sample JSON from form data source tab:

```
{
    "name": "Ken",
    "photo": "www.photo.com",
    "answers": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
}
```

When the express server gets the request it is an empty object {} but returns a status 200 to the browser.

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function formDataToJSON(){
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked");
        var answerArray = [];

        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            var questionName = "question" + i;
            answerArray.push($("#"+questionName).val());
        }
        var objectBuilder = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            photo: $("#photo-url").val(),
            answers: answerArray
        }
        objectBuilder = JSON.stringify(objectBuilder);
        console.log(objectBuilder);            
        ajaxCall(objectBuilder);
        })


        function ajaxCall (objectBuilder) {
            console.log("ajax start!    " + objectBuilder)
            $.post( "/api/friends", objectBuilder, function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
```

routing express code:

```
var express = require("express");
const app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var friends = require("../data/friends.js");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

module.exports = function sendFriendsList(app){
    app.get("/api/friends", function(req, res) {
        res.send(friends);
    });
    app.post("/api/friends",  jsonParser, function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        console.log(req.body);
        friends.push(req.body);
        res.end("done");
        // console.log(friends);
    });
}
```

from the server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

require('./routing/htmlRoutes.js')(app);
require('./routing/apiRoutes.js')(app);
var friends = require("./data/friends.js");
app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App listening on PORT " + port);
});
```

Comment: The Express server gets a request, not a response. The Express server sends back a 200, which means no error (HTTP 200 OK). If it's empty on the Express side, and you're certain the data on the wire is what you intend to send, giving us client code isn't too helpful :)

Comment: @Dave Newton Hi Dave. I added the server code to the post and edited it to say request instead of response. Thank you for your help with this.